# How to deal with CHARACTER variables, longer than the allowed maximum of 2000?

Tags: string, limit, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL, appBuilder and procedure editor, release 11.6.

I've just found a `CHARACTER` type global variable (`DEF VAR global_variable AS CHAR NO-UNDO.`), containing up to 12901 characters. The variable is only used for passing information within the application, the information will never be stored as one tuple within a table.

The information in that variable seems to be handled well: the content is correct.

Yet, as [this URL](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/Character-data-types.html) mentions, the maximum length of a character variable in Progress being 2000 characters, and this makes me worry: I'm afraid that one day, another limit may be crossed and from that moment on, we'll need to rethink the whole idea, and I'd like to be prepared for that day.

Therefore, does anybody know the "next" length limit of a character variable in Progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That reference you mention points to SQL limitations.

In the ABL, a CHARACTER variable can hold ~ 32 k

```
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN c = FILL ("*", 31000) . 

MESSAGE LENGTH (c) 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Beyond that you have to use LONGCHAR with it's limitations:

- slightly slower
- cannot be indexed in temp-tables or database tables.

CHARACTER variables are always stored in the CPINTERNAL codepage. LONGCHAR's can use a different codepage through the FIX-CODEPAGE statement.

Comment: There is also a distinction to be made between a VARIABLE and a FIELD. Not every datatype can be a field (ROWID for instance).